# Newton's 3rd law of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision

Ok my question  iz on the Newton's 3rd law, if every action has an equal and opposite reaction then why we not feel pain when we strike some soft surface like water, cotton but we feel pain when we strike on the hard surface like wall etc etc..

Comment: Do you understand what is meant by "action" and "reaction" in this context?

Comment: Ma answer iz, feeling pain can not solely be associated with force, what about pressure? Or, in your question are you really considering applying a constant force to both surfaces or collision of your hand, because in the latter case local mass distribution will matter for average force exerted on your hand.

Comment: I don't know how pain receptor under ur skin works but I would definitely yell doing bellyflop at a swimming pool and pillow fights

Comment: Pain is an experience not a force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soft surface are the ones that increase the time of impact. In other words since the hard surfaces are rigid, the time of impact is very small. Therefore assume ur hands velocity to be v and once u hit it it becomes 0. For soft surfaces this time taken will be much more than for hard  surfaces. F=m(dv/dt). Therefore f is more on hard surfaces than soft surfaces. U may say that we are applying the same force on the object, but what force ur talking about helps to increase your hands velocity. There fore the change in velocity i. e. dv is same but dt is not same.

Answer (score -1):

Atoms of hard surfaces are strongly bounded with each other and located tightly. We are not able to broke them when we strike the wall. Then, we feel the counter-force and pain.